# Writing javascript in JSX with expression

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand the concept of writing expression in JSX but unable to understand that how is not javascript in curly braces an expression?

```
const Welcome()=>{
  const isLoggedIn = true;
  return(
    <div>
      {
        if(isLoggedIn){
          <p>Welcome!</p>
        }else{
          <p>Please Login</p>
        }
      }
    </div>  
  );
}
```

Please guide me either when we assign a value isLoggedIn is true then validation happens, if value is true then it prints Welcome otherwise please log in.

Please tell me how is this a statement and not an expression.

Comment: `if` statements in JavaScript are statements, not expressions (unlike, say Kotlin). Use a ternary operator or `&& ||` instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: @Ziwon Please explain how can we say that is a statement not an expression.In the block if(isLoggedIn) tell us either is it a statement or expression?

Comment: Expression returns a value. Statements don't return a value. For example you can do `let a = 1 + 2` because `1 + 2` is an expression. However you cannot do `let a = if (1) {2}` because `if (1) {2}` is **not** an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`if` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) in JavaScript are, by definition, statements, and not expressions.

An expression can be considered as code that you can assign to a variable:

```
const myVar = 2 + 2;
const otherVar = someFuncCall();
```

Here, `2 + 2` and `someFuncCall()` are expressions because they can be assigned to a variable.

An if statement *can't* be assigned to a variable:

```
const invalidCode = if (someCondition) { "ABC"; } // This code won't run
```

You can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead, which can be used to create expressions just like any other operators (e.g. `+` operator):

```
const Welcome = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = true;
  return(
    <div>
      {isLoggedIn ? (<p>Welcome!</p>) : (<p>Please Login</p>)}
    </div>  
  );
}
```

This code works, because it's possible to assign this result to a variable:

```
const myJsx = isLoggedIn ? (<p>Welcome!</p>) : (<p>Please Login</p>)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `if` then you have to use `ternary operator` because `if` in java scripts are statements, not expressions.

```
const Welcome = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = true;
  return (<div>{isLoggedIn ? <p>Welcome!</p> : <p>Please Login</p>}</div>);
}
```